# Filtering issues in next Sprint

Tags: jira, jql

I have the following filter to find issues in current Sprint:

```
resolution is EMPTY AND assignee = currentUser() AND Sprint in openSprints() ORDER BY priority DESC, created ASC
```

It works as expected. However, our team creates separate "sprint" (in futureSprints()) for stretch goals and I'm unable to query them without picking up the rest of the backlog. However, this stretch goal sprint is always the next one in our list. Moreover, if current sprint is called "Sprint 20-2016", the stretch goals will be called "Sprint 20-2016 Stretch Goals". This means that I can retrieve the stretch goals by grabbing the name of the current sprint. For example, the following hardcoded solution works:

```
resolution is EMPTY AND assignee = currentUser() AND Sprint in futureSprints() AND Sprint = "Sprint 20" ORDER BY priority DESC, created ASC
```

Problem is that instead of `"Sprint 20"` being hardcoded I want something like `Sprint = [name of first entry from] openSprints()` but don't know how to express this in JQL. Alternatively, since stretch goals are always in the next sprint, something like `Sprint in [first entry in] openSprints() + 1` would work as well.

Comment: which Jira version is that?

Comment: JIRA v7.2.0-OD-03-014

Answer (score 1):

Adaptavist Scriptrunner adds a plethora of extra JQL functions.

One of which is [nextSprint](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/5.0.4/jira/jql-functions.html#_nextsprint)

```
nextSprint("Board Name")
```

I use it to generate statistics for our next planned 3 week sprint as well as feed a dashboard for users that complete their work early and are looking to pull issues from the next sprint into the current. Generally we pull by stack order, but with as much dynamic work as we have a dashboard gives us a bit more flexibility that a scrum board doesn't offer.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(sprint in openSprints()) AND (sprint not in futureSprints())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, openSprints() does not contain the sprint with stretch goals. I don't know if this is a limitation of JIRA or incorrect setup by our PM.

Comment: We use JIRA v7.2.6#72008.  When I type in `sprint in openSprints()`
I get an error message: The operator 'in' is not supported by the 'sprint' field.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could find a way to reference the next 'top' of the board Sprint. However, I think if you are using a naming convention, like Stretch Goals', I would put my filter as

Sprint = Stretch Goals and sprint=futureSprint()

I tried using the word Like, but found out that it is not supported and JQL as it is does a 'Like' search. Using the FutureSprint() check you will not get